# Mostrar en columnas la descomposición en factores primos

Tags: python

> Crea un programa que imprima la descomposición de factores primos de un número. Tu programa recibirá como entrada un número entero y debe imprimir cada factor primo del número en una línea separada. Por ejemplo para el número 22 debiera imprimir:
>
> ```
> 2
> 11
> ```

Ese es el ejercicio.

```
x = int(input("Ingrese numero: "))


def descomponer(n):
    primos = []

    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        while n % i == 0:
            primos.append(i)
            n = n / i
    return primos
```

Como lo imprimo para que me salga el resultado en columnas?

Comment: Lo que retorna tu funcion es una lista. Basta que iteres por cada elemento de la lista y hagas `print(elemento)`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1):

```
x = int(input("Ingrese numero: "))


def descomponer(n):
    primos = []

    for i in range(2, n + 1):
        while n % i == 0:
            primos.append(i)
            n = n / i
            
    for i in range(len(primos)):
        print(primos[i])

descomponer(x)
```

Tu código está muy bien, solamente faltaba imprimir los resultados en columnas. Para ello, simplemente hay que recorrer la lista e imprimir cada elemento.